# My minecraft username is changed but it doesn't appear in-game

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This is what i see: [image: Username is changed]

And this is the game: [image: in-game not changed]

Hope you can help.

Comment: If it doesn't fix itself after a while, try relogging ("Switch User -> "Log Out") and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log in and out of the launcher itself, and your name should update.

Answer (score 7):

Your profile name isn't your in-game name. You can see that your name is changed by looking to the right bottom of the launcher:

[image: The username]

Answer (score 1):

Mojang's systems are cached. Try closing your game client and opening it up again after 10 minutes.

If this does not work, then some weird error has gone on in the backend, and it'd be logical to contact Mojang.

You can check what the Mojang API is showing in a GUI on www.namemc.com